# 32 Bit Applications won't start on Windows 64 Bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit

I've installed the latest Catalyst and other Software on my Windows 7 64-Bit System. Everything was ok but since the last boot all my 32-Bit Application won't work anymore. I figured out that the 32-Bit apps loads the 64-bit DLLs (Dependency Walker helped me here). Using Google I found another person who had that same problem: http://msoos.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/0xc000007b-error-solution/

Fixing the "path" variable didn't helped me here. I can't (re)install the Microsoft Visual C++  2005/2008/2010 x86 bcs. they are 32-Bit apps. ;-)

How can I solve my riddle?

Edit: ErrorCode is 0xc000007b

Comment: Use Windows System Restore pick a date before you installed the Catalyst software.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I discovered the problem went away for me when uninstalling the ATI Catalyst 11.3 software and driver. Alternatively you could try a system restore from a restore point from before you installed ATI Catalyst 11.3. The next problem however is that the 11.4 preview driver also has the same behavior after installing and I'm afraid if I will be able to update ATI Catalyst in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you installed the Windows 7 Service Pack 1 update? I had the same issue and was unable to resolve it. I ended up wiping the system clean and reinstalling fresh in a fit of geek rage.

Comment: Nope, SP1 is not yet installed. The problem began in the moment where I installed the latest ATI Catalyst 11.3 incl. the AMD SDK. Deinstalling did not solve the problem. :|

Comment: Installing SP1 is a good idea and might fix my problem. I will try that first.

Comment: It got worse. Now the system won't boot anymore (Error C0190003 during update). :|

Comment: You could give System Restore a shot. Careful you don't too much after the SP1 upgrade as most configurations only keep the 4 or 5 most recent "restore points". You want to be sure you have a pre-SP1 restore point to get back to.